# Is it possible to share the same Authentication information between two Web Applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two projects. One is an ASP.NET Mvc, and the other is a Web API.

The main project is the Mvc one. But I need to redirect the request to the Web API. All posts about it make clear that in order to redirect to another project, it should be a `Redirect` to an URL:

```
return Redirect("http://localhost:54270/"); //This calls the Get action in the Web API
```

But the problem is that I'm using an Authentication in Mvc that I would like to be validated in the called Web Api Action. **Is it possible?**

The session is not the same, so I cannot retrieve this information. Is there any way to share the same Context between both running sites? Or is it the wrong approach?

Comment: How does your webAPI auth authenticate vs the MVC, is there some kind of transformation you can do to go from MVC Auth to WebAPI auth?

Comment: Can you host your Web API and MVC stuff in the same project? That would probably simplify your setup.

Comment: What are their URL names? Are they two different domain names?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. In webforms, you can set the keys to hash values to the same key in multiple applications. As long as they are in the same domain, that is all you have to do. I have not tried it in MVC, but the internals are very similar. This is a bit of a kludge, but it works nicely.

In this simple way of doing it, you cannot share information, just the high level session information. As I have not played with this in MVC, you may have to set MAC settings or similar to get it to work. I don't have time to look this up. When I found this worked, the developers were still thinking in the ASP world, so they had a boatload of crap in the Session object which we had to sync up. You should not have this issue.

This method will not share the contents of session, but that should not be an issue if you are using MVC correctly.

If you want to go beyond this, there are ways to set up a single sign on mechanism. Anything that works for ASP.NET webforms should work in MVC, although you may have to add some code for items that would not normally be set in MVC that are required for webforms.

If you want a deeper understanding of the way it works, I would look up how people shared state in ASP and ASP.NET, as these pages generally have more information.